# Is it possible to create a material with alternate atom-size layers of 2 different elements?

Tags: materials

For example one layer (one-atom thick) of a superconductor, and the next layer (also one-atom thick, of an insulator, next layer again an atom-thick layer superconductor etc.. until the overall thickness of 1 mm is reached.

If so, how?

Comment: This looks like a ['Novel Idea' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/311/1832). Such questions tend to become moving targets and lead to discussions, neither of which are a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are crystalline compounds that do exactly this - bi-elemental cubics such as face centered cubic, body centered cubic are like this, plus many others.

Common table salt has this structure.

And you really do want to let nature do this for you at it's own pace. If you try to do this forcibly, that force is going to come back out sooner or later. And it adds up fast when you are counting atom by atom.

Comment: And I don't think one atom thick sheets actually have either of those properties, but a two atom thick [florographene](https://phys.org/news/2010-11-fluorographene-world-thinnest-insulator.html#:~:text=Fluorographene%3A%20The%20world's%20thinnest%20insulator) apparently does.